Logitech LIFT mouse thumb button remapping
I have a new Logitech LIFT mouse and want to remap the thumb buttons.
Now the buttons are assigned to go back one page in the webbrowser alt + left arrow and forward alt + right arrow
I want to remap them to ctrl + tab and ctrl + shift + tab so I can cycle through my tabs in the browser and other applications.
I have tried to map them with Solaar following THIS POST but it does not seem to recognise the thumb buttons there. It might also be that I do not understand how "Key Button Diversion" works.
I am unsure how to approach this further, and where to look.
I am running Ubuntu 24.10 and Gnome 47 (Wayland) but am still very new to this.

I just found this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHbFFvxldG4
The program's name is Solaar. You can access to the Github repo.
The video shows how to manage the DPI button, but I'm pretty sure that you can change the buttons with this program. I had the same problem, so I'll try to do it. Good luck!
